# SQLAlchemy Polymorphic Loading

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I've this model in SQLAlchemy:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    type = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    user_name = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

class Client(User):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'client'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    client_notes = Column(Text)
```

This is a joined table inheritance. The problem is when I'm querying User:

```
self.session.query(User).all()
```

all I get is records from clients, while what I want is all record on User without Client. How do I solve this problem?

Edit: I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.7.4 and Pyramid 1.3a3

Comment: Note that your sample code is missing `polymorphic_identity` configuraion for `User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session.query(User)` does not perform any filtering based on the value of `type` column.
However, the `SQL SELECT` statement it generates selects only data from the `users` table (unless `with_polymorphic(...)` is used).

But you can add the `filter` explicitely to achive the desired result:

```
session.query(User).filter(User.type=='user').all()
```